Extension of degree theory on sub-manifolds to manifolds
I am learning the Brouwer degree in the settings of sub-manifolds sztisfying hood assumptions (compactness, orientation, connectedness). I would like to know if there is a reasonable way to extend it to function defined on abtract manifolds ?
I ask this because I have seen that degree theory on smooth functions can be extended to continuous functions and I am curious to know if we can ho further in the generalization.
Thank you a lot !

If you look more closely, you realize that you do not need to work with submanifolds of $R^N$. But if you really want to, you can always quote the Whitney embedding theorem.

Thank you for your comment ! I am working with the book Topology from the differentiable viewpoint and the definition of sub-manifolds given is not (at least for me) easily generalizable to abstract manifold. But I am trying to see, in parallel, another viewpoint based on atlas and I think that it is what you have in mind to see that things can be done without working only on sub-manifolds

Once you have a proper definition of differentiable maps and tangent vectors you do not need an embedding. Take a look for instance in Jack Lee's book how both can be defined intrinsically.

Oh okay, I will look at the reference you gave thank you a lot !
